# Using Annotations Like Marker Interfaces For Javadoc

Tags: annotations, javadoc

I have some conceptually related classes and want to mark them with annotations so that I can see list of these classes in javadoc.

For example, MyAPI supplies some state variables:

```
/**
 * Marker for the state types exposed by MyAPI
 */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface MyAPIState {
}
```

And here is one of these states:

```
/**
 * Stores connection state.
 */
@MyAPIState
public class ConnectionState {
    public boolean isConnected(){...}
}
```

Had I used an empty marker interface for these states (instead of the annotation) I would have easily seen the implementing types. But generated javadoc for MyAPIState does not link to the types which are annotated with it.

Can I make javadoc to show links to the related types in the javadoc of the annotation?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such feature for javadoc, if you don't want to replace the doclet.

Instead of annotations you could try to use custom javadoc tags and combine them with a custom [taglet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/taglet/overview.html) you implement for this purpose.

This could then look like this:

```
/**
 * Marker for the state types exposed by MyAPI.
 * @linktarget
 */
public interface MyAPIState {
}

/**
 * Stores connection state.
 * @linkfrom MyApiState
 */
public class ConnectionState {
    public boolean isConnected(){...}
}
```